# How do I know if my server received no connections within a time period?

Tags: c++, sockets, server

My server hangs on `test=accept(ServSock[i],(LPSOCKADDR)&From,&FromLen);` until it receives a connection. 
How do I make it so if there are no connections after 10 seconds, the server closes?

```
SOCKET test;
    test=accept(ServSock[i],(LPSOCKADDR)&From,&FromLen);
    AmountRead=recv(test, Buffer,sizeof(Buffer),0);
        string xx="abbbbbbfffff55555  rrrrcggggb";
        const char *fin=new char;
        fin=xx.c_str();
        char m;
        fin=xx.c_str();
    RetVal=send(test, fin,xx.length(), 0);
        cout<<"sent: "<<fin<<"\n";
closesocket(test);
```

Comment: set `timeout` yourself through using `select` to set the timeout

Comment: Hmm. So I would do something like this: 
    struct timeval timeout;         
    timeout.tv_sec = 10000;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;
Then have x=select(/*code here before accept()*/); ? Can you help me with using select? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fd_set read;
FD_ZERO(&read);
FD_SET(ServSock[i], &read);

struct timeval timeout = { .tv_sec = 10, .tv_usec = 0 };
if (select(ServSock[i] + 1, &read, NULL, NULL, &timeout) == -1)
  return 1;

if (FD_ISSET(ServSock[i], &read)) {
  int ret = accept(ServSock[i],(LPSOCKADDR)&From,&FromLen);
}
else {
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @EJP "How do I make it so if there are no connections after 10 seconds, the server closes?"

Comment: It doesn't answer the question because he is asking how to tell whether no clients have connected within the timeout, and the answer to that is to test when `select()` returns zero, which you aren't doing in the code you posted.

Comment: You are now conflating 'nothing to accept' with `select()` errors.

Comment: @EJP The OP is not enough clear I suppose that he want to just handle one client. So test with `FD_ISSET` is same behavior of test select with one fd.

Comment: I added your snippet to my program, and it exited after 10 seconds with no clients connected like it is supposed to. Thank you. But something weird is happening with my client. It connects once correctly then tries to connect again and the server and receives -1 bytes.

Comment: @newbcoder I can't help you more with only what you give me.

Comment: Okay thank you. I got it working now. I commented out the accept() line in your example. And used the accept() I had originally implemented. This answered my question.